# Adding line break to bibliography with long numerical doi

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, line-breaking

I am generating a publication list and have a problem about the line break in a bibentry, see below:

[image]

I want the text to be aligned on the right edge and there should be a line break inserted among those zeros. This is a deliberately constructed example. The real life case also contains a doi with a long number at the end, and looks ugly without the line break. This is not a problem of the hyperlink or url package; I can also see it with a long page number at the end of a line.

So my question is how do I insert a line break here.
I am using bibtex with plain and abbrev styles. I can accept a solution that customizes plain.bst or abbrev.bst.

Here is the example. I do not think it is minimal, but I also want the solution to be compatible with other packages loaded. Notice that I entered the doi in the `note` field, so that the plain style can display doi.

Thanks!

compiling sequence:

```
latex mwe.tex
bibtex mew.tex
latex mwe.tex
```

mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{seqsplit}


% to avoid crash of hyperlink and bibentry
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand\publication[1]{%
    \smallskip\par\hangpara{1.5em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip
}

\begin{document}

% bibliography
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
% \bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{mwe}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \publication{test}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

mwe.bib

```
@article{test,
  title = {The annoying Bibtex problem: why the line break is not inserted properly?},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Journal},
  note = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}{doi: 10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}},
  author = {\underline{John Walker} and Smith, Adam},
  month = Jan,
  year = {2020},
  pages = {1000}
}
```

## Update 1

Don Hosek gave two solutions. (Thanks by the way)

1. `\sloppy`
   I use the following commands in place of the enumeration environment

```
\sloppy
\emergencystretch=1em

\begin{enumerate}
\item \publication{test}
\end{enumerate}
```

And here is the result
[image]

You can see that it does solve the problem of line breaking, but more like in a way of Microsoft Word rather than LaTeX.

2. manually add `\allowbreak`
   This is not an automated solution. I will update the reference from Zotero regularly, and I will need to insert `\allowbreak` every time. The place to insert `\allowbreak` may be different between plain and abbrev styles.

While it could solve the problem, I feel the solution is not automated.

## Update 2

Guido's solution (adopted from Mico) solves my problem.

Add xurl package

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

and enclose the url in `\url`

```
note = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}{\url{doi: 10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}}}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the `xurl` package to break (automatically at arbitrary places) a URL (or similar entry), and the `\url` command can be used inside the argument that is used to display and hyperlink of the `\href`. Accordingly,  the `note` field in the original post can be changed to

```
note = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}
        {\url{doi: 10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}}}
```

With the provided MWE it yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take here. One is to use `\sloppy` before the bibliography which will let LaTeX insert wider spaces than normal to allow a break before 10.000/Journal*etc* You may also want to set `\emergencystretch=1em` to allow LaTeX to not just dump all the extra spacing on one line.

The other thing you could do is insert `\allowbreak` in the midst of the digit string to allow LaTeX to do a break in the middle of the digits at the point where you have `\allowbreak`.

Comment: You can use the suggestion by @Mico combining `href` and `url` and loading the `xurl` package. `note = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}{\url{doi: 10.0000/Journal.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}}}`

Comment: @Guido, could you submit it as an answer so that I can accept it?